# Is it possible to see the code behind the AMP components to get a better understanding of how it may work with amp-story?

Tags: components, amp-html, amp-story

Is it possible to see the code behind the AMP **components** to get a better understanding of how it may work with `?

For example, amp-access shows how to use the component. Where can I see how the component is actually built, including the steps involved?

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access

**current topics for amp-access (no coding explanation)**

- Solution
- Specification v0.1
- Integration with amp-analytics
- CORS Origin Security
- Metering
- First-Click-Free
- Login Flow
- AMP Glossary
- Revisions
- Appendix A: “amp-access” expression grammar
- Detailed Discussion
- Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AMP is open source, so you can read the source code of any of its components.  If you want to read the code for `amp-access`, it is [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/extensions/amp-access/0.1).

However, `amp-access` does not directly work with `amp-story`.  Paywall support for `amp-story` is in development, and you can see its progress [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12180).